# On 4.15. Corollary. Conway's Functional Analysis?

Tags: functional-analysis, proof-explanation, hilbert-spaces, compact-operators

The following is from Conway's Functional Analysis:

[image]

Why $[\operatorname{ker}(T - A)^*]^\perp = H$?

Comment: It would be interesting to see (2.19)...

Comment: @Meowdog (2.19) is for the first equality not the second that I am struggling with!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Compactness of $T$ implies that of $T^{*}$. Since $\lambda \neq 0$ and $\overline {\lambda} \notin \sigma_p (T^{*})$ it follows from compacteness of $T^{*}$  that $T^{*}-\overline {\lambda}$ is invertible. Hence its kernel is $\{0\}$ and the orthogoanl complement of the kernel is $\mathcal H$.